# Preserving line numbers when pre-processing Fortran code

Tags: fortran, preprocessor

I have inherited a 10K-lines Fortran code that uses `fpx3` for pre-processing. At this point I should say that I don't have much Fortran experience, and this is my first time dealing with a code that has a pre-processor.

The code works fine, except that when the pre-processing runs, it creates secondary Fortran files (e.g., `main.f90` creates `t.main.f90`) that do not preserve the total amount of lines. The reason, of course, is that some code is lost when pre-processing (IF-ELSE clauses, pre-proc. directives, etc.).

This would be fine, except that when I get a bug in the code, the line number I get from the bug refers to the pre-compiled code (e.g., `t.main.90`) instead of the original code.

This isn't a major problem, but for nearly every bug I have to check the line (say, line 80 of `t.main.f90`) and manually try to find this line in the original (let's say it ends up being line 92 of `main.f90`). I've tried to find a way around this by telling `fpx3` to comment the unused lines instead of throwing them out, but I couldn't find much info on `fpx3` online.

What's the best way around this?

P.S.: I don't know if it matters, but I'm using `ifort` to compile.

Comment: If all else fails you could of course (automatically) add a comment to the end of every line with the line number (provided the source code is in free-form). I read somewhere fpx3 has a line number macro.

Comment: @eriktous Could this be solved by changing to pre-processors?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you mean change to a different preprocessor? I guess, if you can find one that can reproduce fpx3's current effect on your code. I have no experience with preprocessors, so I can't say how easy or hard that will be.

Answer (score 0):

Try -fixed as a .f90 file is assumed to be -free (free form), and fixed preserves the 1st few columns and the continuation in column 6.

If the number at on the right hand side, then NOT -132, but -72 or -80. To not include the numbers as "compilable" code. I use -132, so you have to look up the right switch.